# FSharp.Data.SqlProvider is slow

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers, f#-interactive

I have simple DB with 4 tables. Table `Results` has 18 columns. 3 of them are foreign keys. I am trying to get number of all results (about 800k) with this code:

```
#I @"..\packages\SQLProvider.1.1.3\lib"
#r "FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll" 
open FSharp.Data.Sql


let [<Literal>] ConnectionStringmdf = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10"    

type Sqlmdf = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString =   ConnectionStringmdf,
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
              IndividualsAmount = 1000,
              UseOptionTypes = true, 
              CaseSensitivityChange = Common.CaseSensitivityChange.ORIGINAL
              >
let dbm = Sqlmdf.GetDataContext()

printfn "Results count:\t %i" (dbm.Dbo.Results |>  Seq.length )
```

**It takes about 40 seconds to get count of records in one table.**

Why is it so slow? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Seq.length` causes the whole results sequence to be evaluated. So the time taken includes retrieving all of the data, not just counting the rows. How many rows are there?

Comment: Question updated - it is about 800 000.

Comment: Your code is *NOT* executing `SELECT COUNT(*)`. It's loading *all* data in memory and counting the returned objects. I'd say loading 800K rows in 40 seconds is fast

Comment: Count and its cousins are notoriously slow operators. You are also running on a file based DB, so your HD speed and other operations will impact that. You can do two things, one is check how long it takes for the actual raw SQL query to run, 2. run this query in LINQ. It's not entirely clear where is this being evaluated, maybe locally, not by the server. There is a third option, but you would need to know more SQL Server, there might be special tables and queries that already have this info.

Comment: @s952163 no they are not. And this *is* LINQ. The problem is that `Seq.length` is the equivalent of `.AsEnumerable().Count()` in LINQ. `Seq` *is* IEnumerable after all. `Seq.length` loads the entire table in memory, which causes the delay

Comment: @s952163 `SELECT COUNT(*)` is just an *aggregation*. The server can take advantage of indexing to make it run faster, just like any other query. If you just want to get the number of rows in a table, it's available in the `sys.partitions` table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, I wasn't clear, I mean the same thing as your comment, that instead running the LINQ query on the server, this loads everything into memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types returned by SqlDataProvider implement IQueryable which means you can write a query expression or use `Queryable.Count`

```
open System.Linq

dbm.Dbo.Results |> Queryable.Count
```

or

```
query { for it in dbm.Dbo.Results do
        count
      }
```

Comment: Ok. So I need to use this `query {..}`  to get data from db... But... is there any way how to avoid this `query{..}` syntax? I mean processing data with `pipe |>` and `Seq.someFunction` is really nice way, isn't?

Comment: I already posted how to use the LINQ operators. `bm.Dbo.Results |> Queryable.Count`. `dbm.Dbo.Results` is an IQueryable<T>. You should use the `Queryable` functions, not the Enumerable/Seq functions

Answer (score 2):

You should just execute the query directly on the table, and have the server return the result to you. For example, I get an 8M row count instantenously:

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<connectionString1>

let dbx = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
dbx.DataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled <- false
dbx.DataContext.CommandTimeout <- 60
let table1 = dbx.MyTable

table1.Count()
//val it : int = 7189765
```

You could also wrap it into a query.

Here's a query version, that (unless sqlprovider doesn't do count) should work on the other TP as well. Again, speed is almost instantenous.

```
query { for row in table1 do 
        select row
        count
        }
```

I tested the same with `SqlDataProvider` with similar results. Open the `System.Linq` namespace to access the `.Count()` extension function if necessary.

Comment: The OP is using `SqlDataProvider`, not `SqlDataConnection`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah, yes, I forgot my old SQL Server DBs were wired up with the original SQLDataProvider. I believe the query version should work though. Also if you open the System.Linq namespace, the linq extension methods like Count should work as well. The point being as you commented, to have the query execute on the server not the client and just get the result.